# python как передать параметр в sql-запрос (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, функции, sqlite3, передача-параметров

Создал функцию/метод для класса(в Python) для работы с sqlite3.
В данной функции есть sql-запрос который создает таблицу и вот в качестве параметра этой функции имя_создаваемой таблицы и вот как корректно передать имя создаваемой таблицы в мою функцию

**table_name - параметр функции**

```
def create_table(self, table_name):
        """метод для создания таблицы в бд , table_name - имя создаваемой таблицы """
        test = dataframe_to_sqlite3(self.path_DB_file)      # create example of class 
        cur = test.connect_to_sqlite()                      # method connect_to_sqlite for example 
        print("сейчас будет создана таблица ")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(№ TEXT, Kod TEXT, Nomenklatura TEXT)")    # create Table in DB
        print("создана таблица успешно ")

primer.create_table("Test_proverka")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается через f-строки.
А вообще лучше используй ORM

```
def create_table(self, table_name):
    """метод для создания таблицы в бд , table_name - имя создаваемой таблицы """
    test = dataframe_to_sqlite3(self.path_DB_file)      # create example of class 
    cur = test.connect_to_sqlite()                      # method connect_to_sqlite for example 
    print("сейчас будет создана таблица ")
    cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}("
                   f"№ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                   f"Kod TEXT, "
                   f"Nomenklatura TEXT)")  # create Table in DB
    print("создана таблица успешно ")

primer.create_table("Test_proverka")
```

Comment: О спасибо вам добрый человек даже не знал об f-строках :)